# Compound inequalities with separate variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

So I've got to find the set of elements for which the following inequality holds true:

$$x-2<12\leq6-5x$$

I've only been taught to solve these kinds of inequalities with one x in the middle, so I thought maybe intersecting two different inequalities might work:

$$x-2<12 \wedge 12\leq6-5x$$
Then:
$$x<14 \wedge x\leq \frac65$$
$$(-\infty,14)\cap(-\infty,\frac65 ] = (-\infty,\frac65 ]$$

But apparently it's wrong. Could someone help me figure out what to do instead? Or why this process isn't valid?

Comment: for $12\leq 6-5x$ shouldn't that simplify down to $x\leq -6/5$ therefore the entire thing simples down to $x\leq -6/5$ since $x<14\land x\leq -6/5$ is logically equivalent to $x\leq -6/5$

Comment: yeah, you're right. So just $(-\infty,- \frac65)$, right?

Comment: Yes, you beat me to the sign error...  The point is that the two intervals you found _overlap_.  But both inequalities have to be true at the same time, so only the "lower" one applies.

Comment: Yes I would say so

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: @Joseph though the right most bracket would be a square one like in your question.

Comment: yeah, just a typo, so $(-\infty,-\frac65 ]$. Again, thanks!